# Elasticsearch - foselastica Sorting by integer having strange results

Tags: symfony, sorting, elasticsearch, elastica, foselasticabundle

i want to sort my result of companies based on the count of nested (employment)objects,

i added an extra field to the company entity that holds the count like:

```
private employeeCount;

getEmployeeCount(){
  return count($this->employments);
}
```

and added it to the index like:

```
            company:
                mappings:
                    fullname: ~ 
                    employeeCount: ~
```

the field is correctly indexed and i get hits like:

```
"_hit": {
"_index": "search",
"_type": "company",
"_id": "2628",
"_source": {
"fullname": "acme",
"employeeCount": 9,
... },
"sort": [
"9"
]
```

i added the sort like:

```
$query->addSort(array('employeeCount' => array( 'order'=>'desc')));
```

and the result seems to be sorted correctly down from " 9, 8, 7, 6 ...",

but for some reason there are some results somewhere in the middle with higher employeeCount

for example this:

```
"_hit": {
"_index": "search",
"_type": "company",
"_id": "2668",
"_source": {
"fullname": "acme2",
"employeeCount": 18,
... },
"sort": [
"18"
]
```

i expect this result to be on top of my first example but it is somewhere between 2 and 1

so two guesses, it is sorting from 0-10 and everything greater than 10 is ignored

or there is some bug in elasticsearch or foselastica bundle,

heres the resulting query:

```
search/company/_search (GET) 5.59 ms {"sort":[{"employeeCount":{"order":"desc"}}],"query":{"wildcard":{"fullname":{"value":"**","boost":1}}},"size":"2000","from":0}
```

anybody any idea ?

Comment: I have same problem, Did you found the answer?

Comment: unfortunatly i did not found any solution. Feel free to request the developers, i did not

Comment: i found the answer here :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25199481/elasticsearch-sorting-integer-desc#answer-25200046

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it is sorting as a string instead of an integer. You can add a type to the sort params to specify integer.