# Elasticsearch: sort by a numberic field

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm coding a console app to Insert data from JSOIN files into Elasticsearch 7.5.1. The `_id` field should be an int and act like auto-increment. To make that happen, before inserting I get the last ID inserted and increment 1.

My problem is that I'm having trouble getting the last ID, because the ordering is happening on a string. This is what I mean: if you have `10 items` and the last ID is `10`, when querying and sorting it will return `9`.

This is my query when using Postman:

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "size": 1, 
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
 "sort": [{
      "_id": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And my Java function using [their client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/7.5/java-rest-high-search.html):

```
private static String getLastElasticSearchId(String index)
{
    RestHighLevelClient client = getElasticSearchClient();

    SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(index);
    SearchSourceBuilder b = new SearchSourceBuilder();
    b.query(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery());
    b.sort(new FieldSortBuilder("_id").order(SortOrder.DESC));
    b.from(0);
    b.size(1);
    searchRequest.source(b);

    try {

        SearchResponse searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
        SearchHits hits = searchResponse.getHits();

        if(hits.getTotalHits().value > 0){
            SearchHit[] searchHits = hits.getHits();
            for (SearchHit hit : searchHits) {
                return hit.getId();
            }
        }
        else {
            return "0";
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            client.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Both return 9 as the last ID, even having another item in the index with 10 as ID.

I cannot apply string padding in the IDs as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25199481/elasticsearch-sorting-integer-desc).

How can I achieve what I need?

Comment: If everything is happening in the same process, I would use an AtomicInteger to keep up with the last ID assigned. This would also solve race conditions that would arise if you tried to get the last ID from the records that were already created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "size": 1, 
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "sort" : {
        "_script" : {
            "type" : "number",
            "script" : {
                "lang": "painless",
                "source": "Integer.parseInt(doc['_id'].value)"

            },
            "order" : "desc"
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps